# What is keyboard shurtcut for choosing from google search results directly?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-search

**Problem:** In previous versions of Chrome it was possible to go directly to search result with pressing once <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then use up/down arrows to choose from the results and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to choose it.

Right now, it is possible only pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple times and traverse through each html element.

[Official Chrome shortcut page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en-GB) does not mention that shortcut.

*Google Chrome version:*
`60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it was a feature of Google Instant Search that was dropped in July 2017:
http://searchengineland.com/google-dropped-google-instant-search-279674

Comment: If I understand correctly, the post says that "search as you type" feature was removed. But how about making a search and go directly to first search result with pressing TAB key, yet without traversing a couple of html elements to reach it (as it is right now)?